# Nested async methods... do I need to await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Let's say I have an existing `async` method returning a Task that runs well. It awaits and is itself awaited properly. This method takes an `int` argument:

```
public async Task<MyType> MyMethod(int foo)
{
    // .. do stuff 
}
```

We want to update this method to instead accept a string, and if we can parse an int from the string, then do what we've always done (moved to a new helper method), otherwise, if we can parse a Guid, then a call a different (but very similar) method. If neither type will parse, then return an empty/noop result:

```
public async Task<MyType> MyMethod(string foo)
{
    if ( int.TryParse(foo, out int bar))
    {
        return MyIntHelper(bar);
    }
    else if (Guid.TryParse(foo, out Guid bar))
    {
        return MyGuidHelper(bar);
    }
    else return MyNoop();
}

private async Task<MyType> MyIntHelper(int foo)
{
    // original ".. do stuff" here
}

private async Task<MyType> MyGuidHelper(Guid foo)
{
    // similar ".. do stuff" here, but using a Guid instead
}
```

The question is, in the updated `MyMethod()`, do I need to `await` the results of the helper methods, or since I'm already returning a Task and any necessary awaiting is still in the caller and child methods am I already covered?

As some background, this is in the context of updating a controller to accept an additional "endpoint", but really I'd like to decouple the question from that context as much as possible.

Comment: `MyMethod` doesn't really need to be async. You can just return the task from either helper method. Though that does change how exceptions would be observed by the caller.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman As part of the goal is to otherwise match the original as closely as possible, it should probably stay async. But I'm open to arguments on the issue.

Comment: Since `MyMethod` does all it's work before the first potential `await`, and then just immediately returns the result. Making it an async method just adds complexity. The only externally visible side-effect would be if `MyMethod` threw an exception before that `await`. And the caller would only care if they had something like `var task = ....; <something>; await task;`

Answer (score 5):

> in the updated MyMethod(), do I need to await the results of the helper methods

If you use `async`, then you should use `await`. As a general rule, you should use `async` and `await` for most asynchronous methods.

Anytime you have nontrivial logic (including the possibility of exceptions), you should use `async` and `await`. For trivial method implementations, you can [elide `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) (as described on my blog).